# How do I use COPY FROM on a backup file with multiple tables?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, copy, client

I used this command to backup my "supplies" table:

```
COPY supplies (id, price, ...) FROM 'C:\Users\MyCompany\Desktop\database03-01-2022.sql';
```

But now, I would like to write three more tables' data into that file, and call the same COPY FROM command.

1. Is that possible?
2. How should the file be formatted?
3. Will the COPY FROM command need to change?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: No, not possible. COPY FROM will only insert into a single table. Btw: using `.sql` as the extension for CSV or TXT files is highly unusual.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is it possible to write blocks of COPY FROM's, with data, into a text file and read it into postgres?